# Mouseup doesn't stop the interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousedown, mouseup

I am trying to make a script that toggles class of divs when you hold mouse over them, This is my code:

```
var timeoutId = 0;

$('.block').mousedown(function() {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(heldMouse($(this)), 1000);
}).bind('mouseup', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
});

function heldMouse(starting) {

  if(starting.hasClass('active'))
    {
      $('.block').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
      });
    }
    else
    {
      $('.block').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
      });
    }
  if(typeof starting != 'undefined')
    starting.toggleClass('active');
}
```

My problem is, the classes are still getting toggled even when I release mouse button as if the mouseup bind isn't triggered. What may be the cause of that?

Comment: You're not referencing a function in the setTimeout, you're calling a function immediately and return the result of that function to the timeout. You need to remove the parentheses.

Comment: Also, you're binding event handlers inside event handlers, not a very good idea.

Comment: Ok, I managed to do that with a variable tracking on mousedown and putting mouseover in an IF. Thanks!